# assembly and c - call-by-reference problem

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to implement a function in the assembly where the first parameter is the input value and the second parameter is the return value.I simply try to set the return value to the input value.
I have written a small C program that calls this function.

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void f1(int,int*);

int main() {
    int z1 = 0;
    int z2;

    scanf("%d", &z1);

    f1(z1,&z2);
    printf("A1: %i\n",z2);

    return 0;
}
```

assembly code:

```
 f1:
        push    ebp
        mov ebp,esp

        mov eax, [ebp+8]
        mov [ebp+12],eax

        pop ebp
        ret
```

The output should be equal to the input, but it is a "random" negative int value like "-5870340" or "-3303956".

Comment: Notice your second argument is a pointer. You should dereference it. What you did was `z2=&z1` not `z2=z1` that you intended. The random negative value is the pointer.

Comment: Actually `f1()` doesn't modify `z2` at all.  It only overwrites its copy of the pointer, leaving `main`'s `z2` holding uninitialized garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are passing in a pointer, you need to dereference it to modify the value:

```
 f1:
   push ebp
   mov edx, [ebp+12]
   mov eax, [ebp+8]
   mov [edx], eax
   pop ebp
   ret
```

So, capture the value of the pointer and then move the first parameter to the location that it points to.

Comment: And, depending on the actual platform, compiler and calling convention, do not use `ebx` but rather `edx` or `ecx` for this.